# VSCode prevent file Explorer from jumping

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to prevent VSCode from jumping all over the place when closing a tab?  It jumps to the location of the selected tab, but this is very disorienting when opening various files to inspect within a lib.

Answer (score 385, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the following setting in the `settings.json` file:

```
"explorer.autoReveal": false
```

File -> Preferences -> Settings:

[image]

There is currently no setting for keeping the selected file in the explorer, but this one at least keeps the scroll position fixed and prevents the "jumping".

**Update**

In current versions, the same setting now keeps the selected file.

Comment: @Wosi That was my first thought, but it turns out that the answer is indeed correct. I just expected it to do a little more (keeping the selection). Answer edited, I add the issue we where talking about here in the comment section to keep context somewhat intact: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14745  (The VSCode team is moving so unbelievably fast with the project, the part with the "missing" piece might be obsolete soon anyway :) )

Comment: shifted from sublime to vscode recently, glad this exists

Comment: Unfortunately this controls the reveal behavior when both closing _and_ opening a file. It would be nice to have it reveal when you open a file only and not when you close one.

Comment: Where to add this setting??

Answer (score 56):

After you apply `"explorer.autoReveal": false`, as mentioned above, you can also set up

### a shortcut to force show the current file in Explorer:

```
{ "key": "cmd+e", "command": "workbench.files.action.showActiveFileInExplorer" }
```

Comment: This would be really nice.  How do you setup this shortcut?  Is it in the settings.json?

Comment: You can right click on a tab to show this command option, it's already bound.

Comment: @razorsyntax `Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts`. Add a new line with the above.

Answer (score 23):

As commented in [issue 23902](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23902#issuecomment-521185237) (Option to keep file selected in sidebar without forcing a scroll)

- If set `autoReveal` to true, the jumping inside file explorer is confusing;
- If set `autoReveal` to false, I have to use `showActiveFileInExplorer` keybinding or right click menu every time when switch between tabs

But with [VSCode 1.46 (May 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#explorer-auto-reveal-focus-without-forcing-a-scroll) you now have:

> ### Explorer auto reveal focus without forcing a scroll
>
> There is a new option **`focusNoScroll`** for the `explorer.autoReveal` setting.
>
> When using this option, the Explorer will automatically select files when opening them but will not scroll to reveal them in the Explorer view.