# VSCode: How to turn off auto select in File Explorer when changing window tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, preferences

In VSCode, if I have an editor window tab open and I click anywhere in that editor window, the selected file in the File Explorer changes to the file being edited. I would like to prevent that behavior. This is possible in Visual Studio, but I can't seem to find a similar setting in the preferences file of VSCode.

Can anyone provide some suggestions?

Answer (score 70):

This has been added, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14745.

Configuration is `"explorer.autoReveal": false`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This same behavior happens when you delete a file in the file explorer. When you delete a file then file explorer finds, selects and focuses on the file in the current focused editor. Setting autoReveal to false also prevents this behavior.

Comment: For VSCode noobs (like me) to find the configuration settings use the shortcut: Ctrl + , Or navigate to: File -> Preferences -> Settings

Answer (score 3):

You can't, at least not today. The only thing you can do, is keeping the scroll position when switching tabs. See this answer for the setting: [VSCode prevent file Explorer from jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336835/vscode-prevent-file-explorer-from-jumping/40339047#40339047)

And here is the feature request on Github: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14745

(Feel free to add a "Thumbs Up" via Github Reaction at the top so the request gets more attention in the future, this increases the chances that it gets implemented sooner)